# iPhone stringWithCString is deprecated

Tags: iphone, string, sqlite, cstring, deprecated

I use this code to read data from sqlite database:

```
keyFromSql = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(preparedStatement, 1)];
```

but the compiler give me the warning wrote in the title... so, what is the right and not deprecated method to retrieve a value from sqlite?

thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
+(id)stringWithCString:(const char *)cString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc
```

I think you'll typically use NSUTF8StringEncoding, so your code would look like

```
keyFromSq1 = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(preparedStatement, 1) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Alternatively you can use

```
keyFromSq1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(preparedStatement, 1)];
```

Comment: `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:count encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` is better,  if you think carefully about Apple's document at https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1497290-stringwithcstring?language=objc

Answer (score 5):

Since SQLite always return UTF-8* encoded strings, [you could just use `+stringWithUTF8String:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithUTF8String:).

```
const char* res = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(preparedStatement, 1);
keyFromSql = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:res];
```

<sub>(* or UTF-16, if you use `sqlite3_column_text16`)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:count encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`
is preferred to `stringWithCString:encoding:`

[Apple's Document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1497290-stringwithcstring?language=objc)'s recommendation is not very OK, because the original method "doesn’t stop short at a NULL character."